# Trouble passing variable as parameter between methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, web-scraping

I've created a script in python using ***class*** to log into a website making use of my credentials. When I run my script, I can see that it successfully logs in. What I can't do is find a suitable way to pass `res.text` being returned within `login()` method to `get_data()` method so that I can process it further. I don't wish to try like this `return self.get_data(res.text)` as it looks very awkward.

The bottom line is: when I run my script, It will automatically logs in like it is doing now. However, it will fetch data when I use this line `scraper.get_data()` within main function..

This is my try so far:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring
import requests

class CoffeeGuideBot(object):

    login_url = "some url"

    def __init__(self,session,username,password):
        self.session = session
        self.usrname = username
        self.password = password
        self.login(session,username,password)

    def login(self,session,username,password):
        session.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0'
        payload = {
            "Login1$UserName": username, 
            "Login1$Password": password, 
            "Login1$LoginButton": "Log on"
        }
        res = session.post(self.login_url,data=payload)
        return res.text

    def get_data(self,htmlcontent):
        root = fromstring(htmlcontent,"lxml")
        for iteminfo in root.cssselect("some selector"):
            print(iteminfo.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    session = requests.Session()
    scraper = CoffeeGuideBot(session,"username","password")
    #scraper.get_data() #This is how i wish to call this
```

***What is the ideal way to pass variable as parameter between methods?***

Comment: What is the signature of `get_data()` that you are expecting or trying to achieve?

Comment: That `get_data()` method parses some preferable titles from that site but that is not the issue here. Thanks.

Comment: What I meant by method signature is - parameter list and expected return variables(s). Anyways, I noticed the last line of your code later. Also, I am assuming that you want to access `res.text` inside `get_data()` without passing it as a method argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you requirement correctly, you want to access `res.text` inside `get_data()` without passing it as a method argument.

There are 2 options IMO.

1. Store `res` as a class instance variable of `CoffeeGuideBot`, access it in `get_data()`

```
def login(self,session,username,password):
    <some code>
    self.res = session.post(self.login_url,data=payload) 

def get_data(self):
    root = fromstring(self.res.text,"lxml")
    <other code>
```

2. Almost same as above, but actually use the return value from `login()` to store `res`. In current code, the `return` statement is unnecessary.

```
def __init__(self,session,username,password):
    <initializations>
    self.res = self.login(session,username,password)

def login(self,session,username,password):
    <some code>
    return session.post(self.login_url,data=payload)

def get_data(self):
    root = fromstring(self.res.text,"lxml")
    <other code>
```

Comment: This is so perfect @Supratim Haldar. I never have thought that way at all!! A very simple question that you can give answer in comment. ***How would that be if I wanted to pass that as a method argument?***. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad that it helped, @robots.txt! You mean you want to pass the member variable `res` as argument to `get_data()`? That is not the ideal way of OOP. However, if you want to capture `res` in `main()` and then send it as an argument to `get_data()`, you can use option # 2 above, instead of calling `login()` from `init()`, call it from main and capture `res`. Then call `get_data()` and pass `res` or `res.text` as argument.

Comment: One last thing to know for the clarity of my understanding. Although your suggstion is working, how could you call `self.res` from within `get_data()` meant to reurn data from `login()` even when you didn't define it within `__init__()`, I meant you should have encountered this error `"CoffeeGuideBot" object has no attribute res`.How was that possible? Thanks.

Comment: That's a very good question. There are 2 types of class variables in Python - `class variable` shared by all instances, sort of `static` concept of C++ (eg - login_url), and  `instance variable` unique to each instance (those referenced by self). Python allows to initialize an instance variable inside `__init__` or any other member method. If you want to keep all instance variables inside `__init__` for readability, you can initialize those with `None` and then assign value in relevant method. Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 1):

```
from lxml.html import fromstring
import requests

class CoffeeGuideBot(object):

    login_url = "some url"

    def __init__(self,session,username,password):
        self.session = session
        self.usrname = username
        self.password = password
        self._login = self.login(session,username,password)

    def login(self,session,username,password):
        session.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0'
        payload = {
            "Login1$UserName": username, 
            "Login1$Password": password, 
            "Login1$LoginButton": "Log on"
        }
        res = session.post(self.login_url,data=payload)
        return res.text

    def get_data(self):
        htmlcontent = self._login
        root = fromstring(htmlcontent,"lxml")
        for iteminfo in root.cssselect("some selector"):
            print(iteminfo.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    session = requests.Session()
    scraper = CoffeeGuideBot(session,"username","password")
    scraper.get_data()
```

Comment: @robots.txt updated, just a minor change to your code, i saved login and output data to self._login and in htmlcontent i call this method.

Comment: Yes, this is the way I was trying to look for. Thanks.